# Distance between edges and nodes in graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

How do I configure the distance between edges and nodes (red), i.e. the outer shape of a node(blue)?

[image: Diagram of distance between edges and nodes]

Comment: Perhaps weighting may be used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236804/force-graphviz-force-distance-between-nodes

Answer (score 5):

Here is a technique that you can consider that avoids the need to create a custom node shape. There may be some matters of taste that you may need to address further in order to get exactly what you want.

The advantage of this technique, using [HTML-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html), is that varying the space inside and outside the rectangle becomes a simple matter of changing the inner number of points (here 4) and outer number of points (here 16) respectively.

```
digraph {

node [shape=none]

O [label=<
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="16" CELLPADDING="4">
<TR><TD WIDTH="70">\N</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
>]

{a,b,c,d} -> O

}
```

Result:

[image: GIF rendered by 'dot' for the above graphviz input]

You can change the BORDER and CELLBORDER parameters to show or hide the rectangles. You can adjust their thicknesses although only in multiples of 1 point. I have used the WIDTH parameter to force a width-to-height ratio that causes the aligning of all the arrow tips. Otherwise some of the tips would meet the sides of the invisible outer rectangle.

Answer (score 3):

This is *not possible* AFAIK.

The only option available is using `headclip` to have the edge go to the center of the node or to the edge of the outer shape (as you did in your example).

You may try to add some padding to a node by putting it in a cluster and have the edges clip at the (invisible) border of the cluster:

```
digraph {
  compound=true;
  subgraph cluster1 {
        style=invis;
        2;
    }
    1 -> 2[lhead=cluster1];
}
```

[image: Graphviz diagram]

Hopefully somebody knows a better hack for this...

Answer (score 3):

Like the other answer said, this isn't really an easy feat.  Using a combination of height, width, fixedsize, labelloc, and margin node parameters, you can probably get any desired effect you'd like.  Margin is best is you're looking to expand that distance, but to minimize it you need to use the other params.  For example, this graph would have the arrowheads almost touching the 'O' node's text.

```
digraph {
  node [shape="none" width=.2 height=.2 fixedsize="true" labelloc="top"];

  a -> O;
  b -> O;
  c -> O;
  d -> O;
}
```

[image: graphviz diagram]

Alternatively, if you really want to put in effort, you could create a [custom node shape](http://www.graphviz.org/Documentation/html/shapehowto.html), and do whatever you'd like to it.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP wanted: The arrows are still touching the outer shape of the node - this simply changes the node dimensions. The same way, margin adds space around the node's label, making the node bigger.